# Drawing in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Someone could help me create this in WPF or is too difficult?! I need to draw because inside the white circle, I have to insert text, there is also text in the green.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X7jZ.png)

Comment: Start reading here: [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Can you make this in Illustrator? If so then just do that and use an AI to XAML export plugin. You could also do in Blend quick and easy....but, SO isn't a place for soliciting free work.

Comment: One approach is to compose your image of multiple objects ... square, circles and triangle. I could give you the Path (using Inkscape) for the image but it won't really help much going forward when you have another image to do. But yes it's all possible in WPF.